# TeamCity: Test connection failed due to I/O-Exception

Tags: teamcity

I’m starting to use TeamCity and getting few problems:

I'm trying to create an ssh connection to a unix server(e.g isk-vsrv131)in order to run commands/scripts on the unix server.

I used "Administration->Edit Build Configuration->Edit VCS Root" to configure a new vsc root but as i'm testing the connection i'm getting the following error:

> Connection failed!
>   Test connection failed in TestU1 :: test_bc. I/O-Exception: isk-vsrv13 (isk-vsrv13)

i've tried different configurations including the server local ip/full domain/using Private key instead of ssh password - nothing works.

on teamcity-vcs.log is see the following:

```
[2012-03-26 17:41:33,827]   WARN [on=editVcsRoot ] -      jetbrains.buildServer.VCS - Error occurred in test connection
jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.VcsException: I/O-Exception: isk-vsrv13 (isk-vsrv13)
.
.
.
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: isk-vsrv13
.
.
.
```

1. How can i fixed that?
2. I’ve created a "Build Steps" which includes a 'Runner type: Command Line" - how can i connect those to a specific ssh connection?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems server machine where TeamCity is installed cannot resolve host name isk-vsrv13, hence the java.net.UnknownHostException error. I would try to specify fully qualified name of this host.